# Third umpire in Hockey and Football sports

Tags: football, cricket, video-review, field-hockey

Why there is not a third umpire in Hockey or Football sports as it is in Cricket sport?

Comment: With all due respect, you are asking a lot of questions round the network, almost all of which are getting downvoted and/or closed. It would probably be worth your while taking some time to review the [site tour](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help) for any sites you are posting on, and also to look at questions which tend to get upvoted on those sites, or you will rapidly find that [your account is blocked from asking questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: Specifically with this question, you do not seem to have done any research before posting it; even if you don't get the terminology right, a Google query for [football third umpire](https://www.google.com/search?q=football+third+umpire) clearly shows that such a concept exists.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* video replay in all common forms of both football and hockey:

- association football has [video assistant referees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_assistant_referee).
- American football has [instant replay review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_review_in_gridiron_football); actually performed by the referee rather than a separate official but has the same effect.
- Field hockey has [video umpires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpire_(field_hockey)#Video_Umpires).
- The NHL has [instant replay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_replay#Ice_hockey), either performed by a video goal judge in the arena or by officials at NHL headquarters.